# C# unity Подскажите сайты

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста сайты где лучше всего задавать вопросы по С# unity. Наличие большого количества пользователей сайта приветствуется, для интерактивного общения.

Comment: есть еще gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Просто набираете в гугле "c# unity форум"

https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/

http://unity3d.ru/distribution/index.php

https://forum.unity.com/

https://gcup.ru/forum/59